# Using pagination with the Spotify search API

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, spotify

I'm working on a program that pulls up random songs within a specified genre on Spotify. Each track is denoted by an random 'offset' inside the search query, per the Spotify docs [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-search). But I'm unable to put a number higher than 999 in this (like the total number of songs marked under a genre), otherwise the request 404's.

They talk about using offset "with limit to get the next page of search results" in the docs above, but changing limit to any number 1-50 still returns the same song, it's the offset that matters.

Here's a snippet of my code where I make the final request:

```py
random_offset = str(random.randint(0, 999))
if (int(random_offset) > total):
    random_offset = str(random.randint(1, total))
url = BASE_URL + '?q=genre%3A%22%20' + rand_genre + '%22&type=track&offset=' + random_offset + '&limit=1'
genre_results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

genre_results_json = genre_results.json()
```

Is there anything I can do to use pagination to perhaps randomly iterate through pages of results if Spotify has any, or am I limited to 1000 tracks in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Spotify's API just doesn't allow for more than the first 1000 results to be queried, so I stuck with using 0-999 for my program's random integers.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you copy the code you have but change the random integer limits?

Comment: Yeah I have it set to that right now because it doesn't allow more than 999 in the integer before it 404s. Here's the error I get:  `{'error': {'status': 404, 'message': 'Not found.'}}`

Comment: you could make a random integer generator to pick one of your random integer generators. an example is the random number integer picks 2 so it picks a number 0-999 and after it generates add 1000 to it the amount depends on the one it picks.